# Auto-Fetch All YouTube Videos From Account

Tags: php, html, api, youtube, account

I have been looking through the YouTube API for awhile now, but am not finding a simple way to auto-fetch all videos from a certain account and then display them on the screen.  I am planning on using PHP in order to accomplish this, but otherwise I am open to suggestions of how to accomplish this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly easy task. For PHP the procedure is described in [this url](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Retrieving_Uploads)

As a summary:

- Make sure Zend_Gdata is downloaded and included
- Use the following code to retrieve the listing

  ```
  function getAndPrintUserUploads($userName)                    
  {     
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
    $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
    printVideoFeed($yt->getuserUploads($userName));
  }
  ```